# Kotlin cli application fails to work after updating to kotlin 1.0.0-beta

Tags: kotlin

I boiled the problem down to the following minimal setup - just a hello world. This one works:

https://github.com/ligi/MinimalKotlinCommandLine

when I switch to kotlin:1.0.0-beta-4584 and run ( gradle clean run ) I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class minimalkotlincommandline.MinimalkotlincommandlinePackage
```

with this build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-4584'
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "minimalkotlincommandline.MinimalkotlincommandlinePackage"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.0-beta-4584'
}
```

and this Main.kt:
package minimalkotlincommandline

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello world ")
}
```

Comment: The program works over here, running directly from IntelliJ. Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: @nhaarman is a gradle clean run working for you? The error message is different after clean but there is still a problem

Comment: Keeping up to date with Kotlin changes via http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/ will let you know when something significant changes.  Although nothing is expected post 1.0 for breaking changes, some might happen before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change mainClassName to

```
mainClassName = "minimalkotlincommandline.MainKt"
```

Since Kotlin version M14 [top-level naming changed](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/10/kotlin-m14-is-out/) from `${Package}Package` to `${File}Kt`. More info in [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions).